# Converting "no hole" overflow to one or two hole overflow

Tags: plumbing

I have a watco over flow in my bathtub.  The watco kind just snaps on pipe (no screws).  I want to convert to an overflow with either one or two holes.  How do I do that?  I don't want the watco style anymore. I snapped off the watco overflow plate and I do not see any holes to screw a new one on.  Is it possible to convert this?

Comment: You might [edit] to add a picture. But the retrofit style of this item should have visible screws with the cover off, so you probably have a version with no place to screw to.

Comment: Yes, a picture would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible? - sure. Just takes replacing some parts.

The walls around your tub will probably have to be ripped open to replace the parts in question, unless you happen to have an access door provided (far too rare in modern construction, IMHO.)

As such, **most people** would likely choose to not go through ripping the walls open just to change the cover plate on the overflow, but if **you** want to **you can.**